# When is the solution to a system of equations a convex combination.

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

Consider this example. I am trying to match the mean and variance of a process using a trinomial tree. This gives me two equations for values $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\} $.

$\begin{equation}
\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 + \alpha_3 x_3 = \mu
\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}
\alpha_1x_1^2 + \alpha_2 x_2^2 + \alpha_3 x_3^2 = \sigma^2 + \mu^2
\end{equation}$

such that $\sigma>0$.

Even in the cases where $\mu$ is in the interior of the convex hull of $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$, and $\sigma^2 + \mu^2$ is in the interior of the convex hull of $\{x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2\}$, I am receiving some solutions where not all values are positive.

Is there a way to check for the condition that the solution is positive.

Comment: What do you mean by "receiving some solutions"? Are you using some software to find the solutions?

Comment: Yes, I have solved analytically by hand, and confirmed the solution for a few different set of points.